# I can't see new files throught windows explorer

Tags: adb, windows, shell, files

i can't see my new(!) files on android throught windows explorer while i can do it by ES explorer or adb shell. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: This is a common problem with MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). Android's file scanner hasn't added your file to it's index yet so you won't be able to see it in Windows Explorer. The scanner also runs only when your device is not connected to your PC and runs once at boot (usually at least) and once you plugged it out.

Comment: Thank you! But is there any way to programmicaly force its execution? For example by running an shell command.

Comment: As I have said: Usually if you unplug it, it will run.